# Efficiently choose an integer distinct from all elements of a list

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a linked list of objects each containing a 32-bit integer (and provably fewer than 2<sup>32</sup> such objects) and I want to efficiently choose an integer that's not present in the list, **without using any additional storage** (so copying them to an array, sorting the array, and choosing the minimum value not in the array would not be an option). However, the definition of the structure for list elements is under my control, so I could add (within reason) additional storage to each element as part of solving the problem. For example, I could add an extra set of prev/next pointers and merge-sort the list. Is this the best solution? Or is there a simpler or more efficient way to do it?

Comment: what is the range of those integers?

Comment: Sorting is nearly always a good first step.

Comment: @askmish probably 2**32, aka 4294967296

Comment: @askmish: As stated in the question, the full 32-bit range.

Comment: Are duplicate numbers allowed in the list? Or all numbers are unique.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: The data is a linked list, not an array, and the order of the original list needs to be preserved. As stated in the question, I could add a second set of prev/next pointers in order to be able to be able to reorder the list in-place without disturbing the original order, e.g. to perform a merge sort, but I'm wondering if this is the ideal solution or if there's a better way.

Comment: It might be worth specifying additional information/constraints on the number chosen. For example, does it "have" to be random?

Comment: @askmish: Duplicates are allowed and in fact the common case is that most of the values are the same or several consecutive values, but under pathological load the values could be distributed anywhere over the whole 32-bit space, and I want to be able to handle that without horrible worst-case performance

Comment: There's no need for the chosen number to be random, just distinct from any of the existing values.

Comment: R.. If you are allowed to add an extra set of next pointers, then you could use quicksort based on that extra next pointer. The original orders of the linked list will stay same.

Comment: Instead of doing a full sort, why don't you do a partition keeping track of the highest/lowest numbers in each partition. If there is a gap (i.e. lowest in the first partition is not the smallest possible, lowest in second partition is not immediate to highest in first partition, etc) you pick it and if there isn't you pick one partition of the 2 that its highest-lowest is larger than the size of the partition and do the same. This is O(n).

Comment: Do you know how many items there are on the list when you need to make the selection ?  Is it a large number ?

Comment: @gmch: Typically, it will be fairly low, but it should scale up to the order of millions or so, at least.

Comment: A much more simpler( and perhaps memory heavy)method would be to have a separate, sorted linked list of all the possible numbers(2^32) and compare and delete each node, when you find a match in your problem list. At the end, the first element in the separate list, would be the minimum of the set of missing numbers.

Comment: @askmish again, because there can be 4 billion possible numbers, storing all of them is a bit infeasible

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I am not talking about sorting the linked list. You generate the sorted linked list, whenever you need to find the missing no. in a list. And yes, this would require 4 billion*4 bytes+4bytes next pointer of memory. But would solve the problem in O(n) time.

Comment: @R.. If you are interested in such a solution, I could elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Please express the dynamics of this list and the occurrence rate of finding a non-member integer.  Is list static, growing or growing_and_shrinking?  How does the rate of non-member selection compare to rate of list changes?  Agree about @Deduplicator solution.

Comment: Do you require the lowest available? Also, is insertion into your list O(1) or O(n)? I ask because if insertion into your list requires walking the list anyway, you may be able to speed up finding the next available by making regular insertions/find operations do some of the work of identifying it for you.

Answer (score 8):

Given the conditions that you outline in the comments, especially your expectation of many identical values, you must expect a sparse distribution of used values.

Consequently, it might actually be best to just guess a value randomly and then check whether it coincides with a value in the list. Even if half the available value range were used (which seems extremely unlikely from your comments), you would only traverse the list twice on average. And you can drastically decrease this factor by simultaneously checking a number of guesses in one pass. Done correctly, the factor should always be close to one.

The advantage of such a probabilistic approach is that you are immune to bad sequences of values. Such sequences are always possible with range based approaches: If you calculate the min and max of the data, you run the risk, that the data contains both `0` and `2^32-1`. If you sequentially subdivide an interval, you run the risk of always getting values in the middle of the interval, which can shrink it to zero in 32 steps. With a probabilistic approach, these sequences can't hurt you.

I think, I would use something like four guesses for very small lists, and crank it up to roughly 16 as the size of the list approaches the limit. The high starting value is due to the fact that any such algorithm will be memory bound, i. e. your CPU has ample amounts of time to check a value while it waits for the next values to arrive from memory, so you better make good use of that time to reduce the number of passes required.

A further optimization would instantly replace a busted guess with a new one and keep track of where the replacement happened, so that you can avoid a complete second pass through the data. Also, move the busted guess to the end of the list of guesses, so that you only need to check against the start position of the first guess in your loop to stop as early as possible.

Answer (score 7):

If you can spare one pointer in each object, you get an `O(n)` worst-case algorithm easily (standard divide-and-conquer):

1. Divide the range of possible IDs equally.
2. Make a singly-linked list covering each subrange.
3. If one subrange is empty, choose any id in it.
4. Otherwise repeat with the elements of the subrange with fewest elements.

Example code using two sub-ranges per iteration:

```
unsigned getunusedid(element* h) {
    unsigned start = 0, stop = -1;
    for(;h;h = h->mainnext)
        h->next = h->mainnext;
    while(h) {
        element *l = 0, *r = 0;
        unsigned cl = 0, cr = 0;
        unsigned mid = start + (stop - start) / 2;
        while(h) {
            element* next = h->next;
            if(h->id < mid) {
                h->next = l;
                cl++;
                l = h;
            } else {
                h->next = r;
                cr++;
                r = h;
            }
            h = next;
        }
        if(cl < cr) {
            h = l;
            stop = mid - 1;
        } else {
            h = r;
            start = mid;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Some more remarks:

1. `Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.`
2. Using more buckets (best keep to a power of 2 for easy and efficient handling) each iteration might be faster due to better data-locality (though only try and measure if it's not fast enough otherwise), as [@MarkDickson](https://stackoverflow.com/u/270986) [rightly remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332508#comment39496074_25333715).
3. Without those extra-pointers, you need full sweeps each iteration, raising the bound to `O(n*lg n)`.

An alternative would be using 2+ extra-pointers per element to maintain a balanced tree. That would speed up id-search, at the expense of some memory and insertion/removal time overhead.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the best answer, but I might consider a variant: no additional storage in the elements, and simply repeating the `O(n)` scan `O(log n)` times for `O(n log n)` in a sort of binary search where each step takes `O(n)` rather than `O(1)`.

Comment: Sure, you can accept one pointer overhead per element for O(n) or no space-overhead for O(n lg n). I don't know what's dearer to you there.

Comment: Actually I don't mind the one-pointer overhead at all, but the `log n` factor is tempting since it avoids the need to hold a write lock on the list while performing the operation.

Comment: Well, you don't need a full write-lock: A read-lock, and the sequence-generation secured by an extra lock looks much cleaner.

Comment: (Having just deleted a similar answer...) Instead of halving the range, you could divide into 4 pieces and make half the number of passes through the data.  Or divide it into 16 pieces and make one quarter the number of passes, etc.  Technically that's requiring additional storage (for the 16 counts you'd need to keep track of), but that storage is fairly tiny, and could be statically allocated so that there's no danger of it failing to be available.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: That's most interesting for full passes through all the data, might be a useful refinement in any case due to better data-locality. Makes the code bigger and more complicated though. OP might try that, depending on time to fiddle...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Static storage isn't practical, but the additional storage you describe is plenty small to assume it fits in automatic storage, so I think it's a very practical solution.

Answer (score 4):

I am supposing that integers have random values not controlled by your code.

Add two unsigned integers in your list class:

```
unsigned int rangeMinId = 0;
unsigned int rangeMaxId = 0xFFFFFFFF ;
```

Or if not possible to change the List class add them as global variables.

When the list is empty you will always know that the range if free. When you add a new item in the list check if its ID is between rangeMinId and rangeMaxId and if so change the nearest of them to this ID.

It may happen after a lot of time that rangeMinId to become equal to rangeMaxId-1, then you need a simple function which traverses the whole list and search for another free range. But this will not happens very frequently.

Other solutions are more complex and involves using of sets, binary trees or sorted arrays.

**Update:**

The free range search function can be done in O(n*log(n)). An example of such function is given below(I have not extensively tested it). The example is for integer array but easily can be adapted for a list.

```
int g_Calls = 0;

bool _findFreeRange(const int* value, int n, int& left, int& right)
{
    g_Calls ++ ;

    int l=left, r=right,l2,r2;
    int m = (right + left) / 2 ;
    int nl=0, nr=0;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        const int& i = value[k] ;

        if(i > l && i < r)
        {
            if(i-l < r-i)
                l = i;
            else
                r = i;
        }

        if(i < m)
            nl ++ ;
        else
            nr ++ ;

    }


    if ( (r - l) > 1 )
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
        return true ;
    }

    if( nl < nr)
    {
        // check first left then right
        l2 = left;
        r2 = m;
        if(r2-l2 > 1 && _findFreeRange(value, n, l2, r2))
        {
            left = l2 ;
            right = r2 ;
            return true;
        }

        l2 = m;
        r2 = right;
        if(r2-l2 > 1 && _findFreeRange(value, n, l2, r2))
        {
            left = l2 ;
            right = r2 ;
            return true;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        // check first right then left
        l2 = m;
        r2 = right;
        if(r2-l2 > 1 && _findFreeRange(value, n, l2, r2))
        {
            left = l2 ;
            right = r2 ;
            return true;
        }

        l2 = left;
        r2 = m;
        if(r2-l2 > 1  && _findFreeRange(value, n, l2, r2))
        {
            left = l2 ;
            right = r2 ;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool findFreeRange(const int* value, int n, int& left, int& right, int maxx)
{
    g_Calls = 1;
    left = 0; 
    right = maxx;

    if(!_findFreeRange(value, n, left, right))
        return false ;

    left++;
    right--;

    return (right - left) >= 0 ;
}
```

If it returns **false** list is filled and there is no free range (very least possible), **maxm** is the maximal limit of the range in this case 0xFFFFFFFF.

The idea is first to search the biggest range of the list and then if no free hole is found to recursively search the subranges for holes which may have been left during the first pass. If the list is sparsely filled it is very least probable that function will be called more than once. However when the list become almost completely filled it can happen the range search to take longer. Thus in this most worst case scenario, when the list becomes closed to filled, its better to start keeping all free ranges in a list.

Comment: Why does `rangeMinId` start at 1? Why not 0?

Comment: I like your idea in principal. Could you please detail your algorithm for finding the next free range? I cannot think of how it could be done without significant worst-case time and/or space complexity.

Comment: See the update, so far it seems to work but I didn't had time to test it more or to search in the thick books :)

Comment: Just as an example to test your code - with the array, `[1,12,11,13,6,8,9,10,2,3,4,5]`, and setting the max to 20 (i.e., `left = 0; right = 20;` inside the function) this code seems to fail returning `false` (`left`,`right` end as `5`,`4`).

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right:). The function had jumped over the only free range and everything on the right is filled. I think that it can be fixed if function is called recursively in this case, I will check how and will modify my answer. I am sure that it can be solved and is rather an optimization problem (not to traverse too much the list).

Comment: Although I am far from an expert, the theoretical problem I have here is that I don't see how - without significant space or time - one can keep track of which start and end points for the potential free range are relevant. For any potential free range, you have to traverse the whole list to make sure it is actually free.

Comment: See the update please. Significant time and space can be spent when the list becomes close to filled. Once you find a free range you will not traverse the list for a quite of time until this range is also filled. I admit that the problem is more complex than it seems. I lost about a hour with the new function and still it may be further optimized for the cases when the list is close to fill. But original problem implied that is far from this. I also couldn't found anything about this problem with google so we can ask in StackOverfow to see is there a better solution.:)

Comment: Consider the example in my earlier comment shuffled a bit: `[11,6,8,13,1,5,12,3,4,10,2,9], maxx = 20`. For this, your present code takes `7*n` iterations (where `n = 12`), which is on the order of `O(n*n/2) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: Yes, I have not optimized it. A few changes can highly increase the performance. First, we can count how many items are on the left and right and to check whether to search first left and then right based on this number. This will improve highly performance because we will find also the first the larger range. Second we can use the middle of the range which makes sure that we will have logarithmic complexity. This both small corrections guarantee that we are not going to search in the left corner while there is a large free range on the right.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind an O(n) scan for each change in the list and two extra bits per element, whenever an element is inserted or removed, scan through and use the two bits to represent whether an integer (element + 1) or (element - 1) exists in the list.

For example, inserting the element, `2`, the extra bits for each `3` and `1` in the list would be updated to show that `3-1` (in the case of `3`) and `1+1` (in the case of `1`) now exist in the list.

Insertion/deletion time can be reduced by adding a pointer from each element to the next element with the same integer.

Comment: Thanks. While it has some time overhead, this approach spreads it out well over operations and and is really simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of the book [*Programming Pearls*](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/), and in particular the very first column, ["Cracking the Oyster"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/cto.html). What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

If your list is small, then a simple linear search to find max/min would work and it would work quickly.

When your list gets large and linear search becomes unwieldy, you can build a *bitmap* to represent the *unused* numbers for much less memory than adding 2 extra pointers at each node in the linked list. In fact, it would only be 2^(32-8) = 16KB of RAM compared to your linked list being potentially >10GB.

Then to find an unused number, you can just traverse the bitmap one machine-word at a time, checking if it's non-zero. If it is, then at least one number in that 32- or 64- bit block is unused, and you can inspect the word to find out exactly which bit is set. As you add numbers to the list, all you have to do is clear the corresponding bit in the bitmap.

Comment: Good answer in general, but your memory calculation is wrong. The bitmap would require `2^32` bits, which is `2^32 / 8 = 2^29` bytes. And 2^29 is 512 MiB which *is* significant.

Comment: Not only is it significant; it also violates the no additional storage requirement. Even if additional storage in elements is costly, it's done at element allocation time when failure it an option. Whereas this kind of external storage could fail to be available at a time where it's not an option.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to take the min and max of the list with a simple `O(n)` iteration, then pick a number between `max` and `min + (1 << 32)`. This is simple to do since overflow/underflow behavior is well-defined for unsigned integers:

```
uint32_t min, max;
// TODO: compute min and max here

// exclude max from choice space (min will be an exclusive upper bound)
max++;

uint32_t choice = rand32() % (min - max) + max; // where rand32 is a random unsigned 32-bit integer
```

Of course, if it doesn't need to be random, then you can just use one more than the maximum of the list.

Note: the only case where this fails is if `min` is 0 and `max` is `UINT32_MAX` (aka 4294967295).

Comment: @Deduplicator The idea is that the list *may* contain numbers between `min` and `max`, but nothing outside that range. The theory is then to pick between `max` and `min + UINT32_MAX + 1`, and exploit auto-reduction modulo `UINT32_MAX + 1`. The maximum picked number is, in theory, `min + UINT32_MAX`. But because it uses 32-bit integers, it wraps around to `min - 1`.

Comment: This approach could easily fail. In particular, if I plan to add the chosen number to the list and then perform the same operation again in the future, it will start failing after a very small number of rounds.

Comment: @Deduplicator added a note about RNG being optional.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is one really simple solution. Some of the answers have become too theoretical and complicated for optimization. If you need a quick solution do this:

1.In your List add a member:

```
unsigned int NextFreeId = 1;
```

1. add also an std::set<unsigned int> ids
2. When you add item in the list add also the integer in the set and keep track of the NextFreeId:

int insert(unsigned int id)
    {
       ids.insert(id);

```
if (NextFreeId == id) //will not happen too frequently
{
    unsigned int TheFreeId ;
    unsigned int nextid = id+1, previd = id-1;
    while(true )
    {
        if(nextid < 0xFFFFFFF && !ids.count(nextid))
        {
            NextFreeId = nextid ;
            break ;
        }

        if(previd > 0 && !ids.count(previd))
        {
            NextFreeId = previd ;
            break ;
        }

        if(prevId == 0 && nextid  == 0xFFFFFFF)
          break;  // all the range is filled, there is no free id

        nextid++ ;
        previd -- ;
    }
}

return 1;
```

}

Sets are very efficient to check if a value is contained so the complexity will be O(log(N)). It is quick to implement. Also set is searched not each time but only when the NextFreeId is filled. List is not traversed at all.

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirements; this set obviously requires additional storage.

Comment: Yes. But you will not need for the set much more storage than if you add two pointers in the list items. Also set is staying in the memory and all operations are faster. The list may stay in this case on the hard disk or another storage. If you notice we are not accessing the list at all.

Comment: "No additional storage" means, conceptually, there is no malloc and there is no hard disk. There are only local variables and the list elements.